# Got error "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" when using X11

Tags: 18.04, ssh, xorg, vnc, debian

1. What the environment like:
   Local host is Ubuntu 18.04, remote host is Debian 9. There are some virtual machin on remote host.
2. What I found:
   Today I want to management virtual machines on remote host, by using  `ssh -x` as usual. But this time I logon, it note `xhost:  unable to open display ""`. And when I execute `virt-manager`, it shows like this:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(virt-manager:16045): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

3. What I tried to solve this problen:
   First I checked my local host's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and make sure it have configured like below:

```bsh
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

And then check the remote host's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and make sure it have configured like below:

```bsh
 X11Forwarding yes
 X11DisplayOffset 10
 PrintMotd no
 PrintLastLog yes
 TCPKeepAlive yes
```

And then I execute `virt-manager`, it still shows like below:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(virt-manager:16045): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Then I tried few commands like below, it seemes useless.

```bsh
$ sudo vncserver

New 'My_Local_Host:15 (root)' desktop at :15 on machine My_Local_Host

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /root/.vnc/My_Local_Host:15.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd :15 to connect to the VNC server.
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:15
$ xhost +
xhost:  unable to open display "localhost:15"
```

Finally I installed `gksu` and tried to open `virt-manager` by it, but it still useless:

```bsh
gksu virt-manager 

(gksu:17242): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:15
```

Can you give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed "xauth" on the server side? Sometimes it displays errors when not installed.